# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] (Error came up when I included chart.js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

Been trying to figure out what the problem is for quiet a while now. Need help

**My HTML**

```
<script src="../Framework/js/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>

<script src="../Framework/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="../Framework/js/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Framework/js/angular-chart.js"></script>

<script src="../Framework/js/plugins/sortable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Framework/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Framework/js/locales/fr.js"></script>
<script src="../Framework/js/locales/es.js"></script>
<script src="../themes/explorer/theme.js"></script>
<script src="../Framework/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Framework/js/app.js"></script>
```

**My app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies','chart.js']);
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH4Kb.png)

Comment: I see you've included `angular-chart` two times in your scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is , angular-charts and chart.js should have the correct versioned library references.

**DEMO**

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp', ['chart.js'])
  .controller('myController', [function() {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.socialChart = {
      options : {
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            stacked: true
          }]
        }
      },
      type: 'StackedBar',
        labels: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
        series: ['FACEBOOK', 'GOOGLE', 'TWITTER', 'INSTAGRAM'],
        colors: ['#ED402A', '#F0AB05', '#A0B421', '#00A39F'],
        data : [
      [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40],
      [28, 48, 40, 19, 96, 27, 100]
    ]
    }
  }]);

})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Multi Slot Transclude</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-chart.js/1.0.3/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
  <canvas id="outreach" class="chart chart-bar" chart-labels="ctrl.socialChart.labels" chart-data="ctrl.socialChart.data" chart-series="ctrl.socialChart.series" chart-colors="ctrl.socialChart.colors" chart-options="ctrl.socialChart.options"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you check the demo

Comment: Yes, I checked the demo! Still can't figure out the problem!

Comment: @AbdullahSultan problem is the version

Comment: Do you think it might be the other js files!?

Comment: Yes, it works when i remove chart.js from the module dependencies!

Comment: Then the problem is with the chart.js reference

Comment: What might be the problem with it!?

Comment: Apparently I forgot to apply the script on the login page!

Comment: I will add you on skype though in case I have another problem.